# Find the gradient of a line passing ($\frac12$,0) and normal to curve $x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = 1$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $C$ denote the curve 
$$
x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = 1.
$$
Let $P$ denote a point on the curve $C$ in the first quadrant. Let $L$ denote the normal line to curve $C$ at point $P$. If $L$ passes through the point $(\frac12, 0)$, find the gradient of line $L$.

I did implicit differentiation on the $y$. And ended up with

$$
\dfrac{dy}{dx} = -\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)^{1/3}.
$$
How would you approach the question?

Answer (score 1):

You have made a good start.  Now remember that the slopes of perpendicular lines have the product $-1$, so the slope of the normal at the point $(x_0,y_0)$ is $\left(\frac {x_0}{y_0}\right)^{1/3}$.  The equation of the normal through $(x_0,y_0)$ is then $y=\left(\frac {x_0}{y_0}\right)^{1/3}(x-x_0)+y_0$.  Plug your point $L$ into this and you get one equation for $(x_0,y_0)$.  You also know that $(x_0,y_0)$ is on the curve, which gives a second equation.  Solve them simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a,b)$ be the intersection between L and C. The distance between $(0.5,0)$ and $(a,b)$ is

$$d^2=(a-0.5)^2 + b^2 = (a-0.5)^2 + (1-a^{2/3})^3$$

Take the derivative and set it to zero to minimize the distance, hence, the normal line,

$$a^{1/3}(a-\frac 12)-(1-a^{2/3})^2 =0$$

which, after simplification, is a quadratic equation in $a^{1/3}$ and we have the solution,

$$a = \left( \frac {17+\sqrt{33}}{32}\right)^{3/2}; \>\>\>b =\left( \frac{15-\sqrt{33}}{32}\right)^{3/2}$$

Then, the gradient of the distance line can be obtained as

$$k=\left(\frac{9+\sqrt{33}}{6}\right)^{3/2}$$